# How to disable voice chat in GTA V?

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v

How do I shut down the voice chat? I can't find any options to silence other players.

Comment: Xbox or PS3? Xbox has a built in feature but you'll need to re-enable it, I'm not a PS3 player, someone else can help there I'm sure

Answer (score 7):

To turn off voice chat on PS3:  Hold down Select then scroll down the Interaction Menu to Chat. Switch it over to whichever setting you prefer.

No-one, Crew, Friends, Crew + Friends, or Everyone

Note: Changing this setting can effect your ability to succeed in a Rally Race. Also, it appears that you cannot change this setting once you've joined a lobby. So you may want to consider enabling voice chat before starting a mission.

Comment: Not working for the race missions... that's annoying as hell

Comment: Unless my driving partner just didn't have a headset or was refusing to cooperate. I'll try another Rally Race soon and confirm those findings.