# How do I disable my mic?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I don't want people to be hearing my conversations, my coughing, me pressing the controller, etc.

If you could tell me how to disable it I would be very pleased.

Comment: Which platform are you playing on?

Comment: If PS then this may be your solution: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133299/how-to-disable-voice-chat-in-gta-v

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable your Microphone, there should be an on and off switch on the side.

If you want to disable your Kinect Microphone, the Xbox website has a quick tutorial here: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/kinect/turn-kinect-features-on-or-off

I'm fairly certain there is not a way to disable your microphone from the GTA menu, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On Xbox One and Xbox 360, you can join a party alone and lock it from others joining without an invite.